# [tailwind]What are those faintly visible lines on the checked radio? How to align checked images?

Tags: input, radio-button, tailwind-css, radiobuttonlist, tailwind-3

What are those faintly visible lines on the checked radio? How to align checked images?

[image]

```
input {
    @apply border-Neutrals-Grey3 checked:border-Brand-Primary ring-0 ring-inset checked:bg-radio_checked checked:bg-[center_left_right] checked:bg-no-repeat checked:bg-[length:7.99px_7.99px] checked:text-Neutrals-White;
  }
```

Aligned input image and disappearing faint lines